# NSOperation for persistent thread

Tags: cocoa, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I have an external tool (written in perl) that does work through a C++ object interface. The launching and tear-down take time so I'd like to have an NSOperationQueue and 4 NSOperation threads that run throughout the life of my app but only do work when I feed them a file to work on. I can round-robin feed them as every file will take roughly the same amount of work.

How can I best do this, or is this asking too much of NSOperation in a way it was not designed to do.

I have tried a normal NSOperation task for each file and the launch & tear-down of the perl tool slows things down and sometimes hangs (not sure why - but seems related to the launch process happening too quickly in sequence).

I'm looking to launch the perl tool once on each of 4 threads and then keep them around for the life of the app as the perl tool will stay open waiting for commands... but those commands have to come from the thread that were launched from.

Comment: Question is a little confusing.  This is in a macOS app?  Is the perl tool executing as a command line tool?  Or are you loading the perl interpreter into the macOS app and executing the perl code in the app's execution space?  How are you going to communicate with the tool after you've run it? Standard In?

Comment: Perhaps NSTask which allows for controlling an executing external subprocess (send it commands and more input via standard in) would work better for you?  You could run multiple instances of your external tool by creating multiple NSTask objects and then pipe input to each of them as needed.  This lets your tool keep running listening for input on standard in.

Comment: Maybe you can monitor stdout to know when the external tool is ready for a new input file.  You'll need some way to know when it's ready for a new input file.